# Following MVC architecture in a modern Java SE project

Tags: java, opencv

I'm doing a Java SE, standalone project using OpenCV. I'm using NetBeans IDE for this project's implementation.

When developing User Interfaces I do it just by drag and drop (using UI libraries). If so, is it a better way to design it in to "Model, View, Controller" architecture?? Are the "Controller" classes still needed or better to use "View and Model" classes only?

Comment: you drag swing components ?

Comment: That all depends - how long is a piece of string? Realistically, if you're making a small toy application then MVC/MVP is likely overkill. But if you are developing anything remotely complicated, then being rigorous with design and layering will save you hundreds of man-hours in the long run.

Comment: @FastSnail NetBeans has a [GUI builder](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart-gui.html). It generates the absolutely worst code known to man, but if it's kept strictly in the View layer that's not catastrophic. Once you start mixing business logic with autogenerated GUI code then it's probably too late to rescue the application...

Comment: even if you use gui builder please set appropriate layouts.lot of people drag and drop components to absolute layout

Comment: Yes, I drag swing components. But referring to some articles, they were mentioning MVC is outdated because of UI libraries using. [link](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/149335/on-mvc-can-several-views-have-the-same-controller-or-one-view-must-have-one-uniq?newreg=d54d5d31b9fe4bfc8c349ba4c2eaf46e)

Comment: Personally I use view and models only.